# R - modify order of levels in tapply function

Tags: r, dataframe, tapply

I have data which looks like the following

```
nums      r     a
1 3     210     0
4 6     3891    1
9 8     891     1
1 3     321     1
8 1     32      0
etc     etc     etc
```

I'd like to compute a few things, and was wondering if anyone can help provide code for the following

1. The mean `a` value for each `nums` value (e.g., above, the average `a` for `1 3` is `0.5`), sorted by the highest average `a` value. I'm thinking `tapply` would solve this, but I don't know how to handle the sort component.
2. The mean `a` value for each `nums` value, sorted by a predetermined `nums` order. E.g., something like `tapply(df$ac, df$nums, mean, orderBy=c("1 3", "4 6", "8 1", etc.))`. You can assume I have an ordering that covers every possible `nums` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tapply`:

```
agg <- with(data, tapply(a, nums, FUN = mean))
```

Then for 1, do:

```
sort(agg, decreasing = TRUE)
```

For 2, do:

```
agg[predetermined.nums]
```

---

You can also use `aggregate`:

```
agg <- aggregate(a ~ nums, data, FUN = mean)
```

Then for 1, do:

```
agg[order(agg$a, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

For 2, do:

```
agg[match(predetermined.nums, agg$nums), ]
```

Comment: For tapply, #2 doesn't work. For aggregate, #2 works, but it outputs as a data frame, not as tapply normally outputs.

Comment: Hard to tell since you did not provide a reproducible example... Can you figure it out yourself? It is simple indexing after all.

Comment: Maybe simple for you, but I am somewhat new to R. Could you reformat the output of your aggregate method to look like the output of a tapply call?

Comment: Most likely you have a factor, so try `agg[as.character(predetermined.nums)]`. In the future, please provide a reproducible example and try to give more helpful feedback than "it doesn't work".

Comment: Reproducible example: data = data.frame(nums=c("1 2 3","4 3 2","2 5 2","4 3 2"),a=c(1,0,1,1)); agg=aggregate(a~nums,data,FUN=mean); agg[unique(data$nums)];

Comment: Yep, the as.character fixed it. Thanks for your help and your patience.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the reproducible example ... ?